# JSON as value of hidden input element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

The following is the JSON which is set as value to the hidden input field in a form:

```
 var stockused={
 "fuel": {
  "1": "248",
  "2": "385"
 }
};
```

using : `$("#the_input_selector").val(JSON.stringify(stockused, null, " "));`

```
<form action="mycontroller">
    <input type="hidden" id="the_input_selector"/>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted i get on the controller script `[object Object]`.

I want to insert this JSON into DB

Some insights please.

Comment: I can't [reproduce](http://jsbin.com/fimaweki/1/edit?html,output) your problem.

Comment: you'd need a action and submit the form, at the action its recieved as `[object Object]`

Comment: You can see the text value it would submit in the example I linked to. It isn't going to convert it to a basic stringified object just because the form is submitted.

Comment: Yes you are right. it is not a submit problem.

Actually the `stockused` variable is changed dynamically on change event of a multiselect and a jquery slider.

When i paste `$("#the_input_selector").val(JSON.stringify(stockused, null, " "));` in console the value comes in same way as you mentioned in your example.

But in script it turns it into `[object Object]`

Comment: Problem resolved, it was a small typo in `JSON.stringify` call